# How to save and load callbacks upon resuming training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Currently I’m using callbacks in Keras to checkpoint the model based on lowest validation loss.
Since the model requires 5-6 hours of training per epoch, I get roughly 2 epochs completed before Google Colab disconnects. Therefore, every time it disconnects, I will resume training from the last checkpoint.

As of now, I am using the model.save and model.load to retain all information about the callbacks, weights and training configuration.

For the first time training the model:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(classifier,
                              monitor="val_loss",
                              mode="min",
                              save_best_only = True,
                              verbose=1)

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', 
                            min_delta = 0, 
                            patience = 20,
                            verbose = 1,
                            restore_best_weights = True)
  
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss',
                              factor = 0.2,
                              patience = 10,
                              verbose = 1,
                              min_delta = 0.00001)

callbacks = [earlystop, checkpoint, reduce_lr]

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
      epochs = epochs,
      callbacks = callbacks,
      validation_data = validation_generator,
      validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size)
```

For resuming training:

```
model = load_model(classifier)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs = epochs,
    callbacks = callbacks,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size)
```

However, every time I resume the training, val_loss is set back to infinity. Therefore, the latest epoch will overwrite the previously saved one from before. Is there any way to save the monitoring value of validation loss?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, after the first resumed epoch the model is saved simply because val_loss is improved from inf, without regard of the actual loss of the loaded model.

My network is slow and I have time limited access on the university HPC, so this was frustrating because every time I resumed my training, the first few epochs were lost to get back the network to original val_loss.

But I think I figured out where the problem is. The issue is in file, at line 360:

- /home/usr/python/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py

in ModelCheckpoint the variable **self.best** is the loss value of the previously saved best model. This quantity is compared to the current **val_loss** (varibale **current** in on_epoch_end, line 424) at the end of the specified epoch, and based on that a model with lower loss is saved (or higher accuracy).

When starting from begin **self.best** is initialized to **Inf** (positive or negative depending if you are using loss or accuracy), but in case of resuming this should be reset to a value. This is because the standard ModelCheckpoint has no information that it's a resuming training, so it's consider a resuming training as a new one.

As a quick fix, I modified the ModelCheckpoint, so that I can actually pass the variable **best** that correspond to the loss of the saved model (otherwise Inf if not specified) plus some minor changes. Such that:

```
    resume_loss, _ = model.evaluate(X_valid, y_valid, verbose=1)
    SaveModelCheckpoint(..., best=resume_loss)
```

Here the my customized ModelCheckpoint:

https://github.com/micbia/SegU-Net/blob/master/utils_network/callbacks.py#L141